# Как реализовать такой слайдер?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Попался в руки интересный проект.
Слайды из презентации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие фуллпейдж слайдеры знаю, ни один не подходит.
Что подскажите? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Копай Google Поиск. И делается это пальчиками рук, или, в крайнем случае, ног :)

Comment: @Yuri дико извиняюсь, но по запросу fullscreen slider выводятся готовые решения, которые мне не подходят. Поэтому я и задал вопрос здесь. Мне не нужны готовые решения, я прошу подсказки, в какую именно из сторон мне копать

Comment: Бери готовые фуллпейджи и переделывай под себя или смотри, как сделали они и пытайся повторить у себя основные части.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функционал полностью реализован самостоятельно.
[Ссылка](http://new.rofas.kz/)